# CSS menu using image sprite with transparencies

Tags: css, menu, css-sprites

This is my issue.

I have a menu using an image sprite, the image has transparencies, but when I add a :hover, it works, but I am still able to see the original image at the end.

Is there a way to make the hover show the image that I want and REPLACE the original one?

Thanks,

Marco

Comment: Some CSS for this would help.

Comment: What exactly is your hover doing. You mentioned image transparency, How is it related to this issue. You need to clear up your question to get answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace an image by using it as a `background-image` instead of using the `<img>` tag.

But most of the times, this is slow and another way is maybe good practice:

1. Create an image that has the :hover image next to it [img|hoverImg]
2. Do a styling with background-position to change the background.

Like this:

```
.menuItem
{
    background-image: url('hello.jpg');
    width:100px;
    height:30px;
}

.menuItem:hover
{
    background-position: 100px; /* Or whatever measure your image is */
}
```

The problem with this, is that the image size is fixed. You really have to specify it, instead of just doing this with an image.

I like this as the best way. If you want to set the `src` in your `<img>`, this can be done with Javascript, but is much heavier most of the time, because you have to load an extra image from the server.

Comment: Marnix, that did the trick ! I was using background-image in all of them, now it works.